# Is it possible to have more than 2 layers of sub report in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a master report and a SubReport1. Inside the SubReport1 I have SubReport2 and SubReport2 has SubReport3. When I run the report all I can see are Master, SubReport1 and SubReport2 but no SubReport3. Have anyone tried this before?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it

Comment: @TheOnlyIdiot `Is it possible to have more than 2 layers of sub report in jasper report?` - Yes, you can use subreport in another subreport

Comment: Hi everyone. I already figured out what was wrong. I forgot to change from Groovy to Java the SubReport3. I did not notice it right away because I did not get any error result its just no display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all yes it is possible, and the way you call the second level subreport is the same. Some example of your actual code would be helpful to understand your drawback, anyways, here is a question similar to yours: [Displaying SubReport inside SubReport](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/532528/displaying-subreport-inside-subreport)
And here is a step-by-step tutorial on how to achieve this: [Call to subreport on existing subreport](http://hamroblog-sristi.blogspot.com/2011/04/ireport-call-to-subreport-inside.html)